# <Verilog> May I know why EQ=1, but the output no response?

Tags: verilog, quartus, fsm, state-diagram

I am trying to build a Finite State Machine vending machine which consists of Datapath Unit and Control Unit. The attached links is the Control unit which consists the input of EQ(Equal), GT(Greater) and product. When product is "1" and either EQ or GT is "1", the output will be out=product. However, in my problem, the verilog code shows correct for GT but not EQ. It seem that the output cannot response to EQ when it is high.

My design of the state diagram.  [State Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPniT.png)

My Verilog code. [Verilog code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHocp.png)

The result. [Result Waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH1K8.png)

```
module dispense(
  input [1:0] product,
  input GT, EQ, rst, clk,
  output [1:0] out,
  output reg done,
  output R
  );
  reg [1:0] ps,ns; //Present State and Next State
  assign R=EQ||GT;
  //State encoding
  parameter [1:0] S0=2'b00, S1=2'b01, S2=2'b10;
  //Verilog segment Next State logic and Output logic
  always @*
    begin
     //out=0;
     done=0;
     case(ps)
       S0: if(product>0) ns=S1; else ns=S0; 
        S1: if(R) ns=S2; else ns=S1;
        S2: begin  done=1; ns=S0; end
        endcase
      end
        //out=product;
    
    assign out = (done==1)?product:0;

    //State Register
    always@(posedge clk)
        if (!rst) ps=S0;
        else ps=ns;
endmodule
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please learn how to [ask] a question so people can help you.

Comment: I am trying to build a Finite State Machine vending machine which consists of Datapath Unit and Control Unit. The attached links is the Control unit which consists the input of EQ(Equal), GT(Greater) and product. When product is "1" and either EQ or GT is "1", the output will be out=product. However, in my problem, the verilog code shows correct for GT but not EQ. It seem that the output cannot response to EQ when it is high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple. Add `ps` and `ns` to your simulation charts and you will understand why.

At the beginning of your simulation you are in state `S0`. When the `product` is bigger than `0` (first yellow mark) you go to state `S1`. Then you are waiting for `EQ` or `GT`, but `EQ` fall down one clock cycle ago so next `GT` arrive.

Set `EQ` and `GT` one clock cycle later.